# How do I use CIN to capture two different data types in one line?

Tags: c++, stdvector, cin

It's a homework assignment: Basically, I need to capture a line using `cin` line like:
`mary_smith 10 9 10 3 100 8 7.5 10 73 9 10 5 9 87 -1`

... then put the name in a string vector, and the numbers (grades) in a multidimensional vector with the same index.

So far I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector<string> names;
vector< vector<float> > grades; //Multidimensional vector for grades
string tempName;
float tempGrade;
int student = 0;

int main(){
    do {
        cin >> tempName; //Get the first entry before whitespace
        names.push_back(tempName); //Push the name into the vector

        //For all the other inputs, put the respective grades at the same base index?
        for (int i = 0; tempGrade > 0; ++i) {
            cin >> tempGrade; //Get all grades until -1
            grades[student][i].push_back(tempGrade);//Add grade to the index.
        }
        ++student;
    } while (tempName != "KEY"); //If you see KEY, kill the program.
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the problem is the machine treats all entries like a `string`. Why won't it start iterating on my `for` loop?

**Update**
Previously I had said it needs to be in a multidimensional array, but I meant vector. I updated this above.

Comment: I'm surprised that code even compiles, much less runs without crashing. The variable `grades` is a vector of vectors, but you use it as a vector of vectors of vectors.  You also don't add the sub-vectors in the outer vector anywhere, so any indexing will be out of bounds.

Comment: There's also a logical problem, in that the the line with `"KEY"` will be read and added to the vectors as well, which might not be quite what you want.

Comment: Your grades vector will start out empty, so you're accessing arrays out of bounds. You need to `resize` or `reserve` or something before you even think about trying to use the `[]` operator.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Doesn't push_back resize it, as it does with `names.push_back(tempName)`?

Comment: It would, it you were using `push_back` as a member of `grades`. You're accessing a vector within grades (that doesn't exist yet), then a vector within that (although you shouldn't be because it isn't 3 dimensional and wouldn't exist yet) and using the method `push_back` of that 3rd dimension vector

Answer (score 2):

Your `tempGrade` variable starts out as 0

Answer (score 1):

Your loop condition is `tempGrade > 0`; but at that point `tempGrade` is still zero, so the loop is never entered. Check the value *after* reading it, inside the loop body; or perhaps restructure the loop to `do {} while (tempGrade > 0);`

Likewise, you probably want to check for the magic `tempName` value and exit the loop before trying to read grades for it.

Then you'll find that `grades[student]` is invalid, since you never resize `grades` from its initial empty state. Presumably, you've already fixed `grades[student][i].push_back(tempGrade);` in your real code, since that wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Answer actually goes to CoffeeandCode.

The vectors don't have an initial length:

```
vector<string> names;
vector< vector<float> > grades;
```

should be

```
vector<string> names(1);
vector< vector<float> > grades(1);
```